# Calendar Field Type

Tags: module, fields, calendar

I have implemented a module which has a Calendar Type as following:

```
<field name="file2calendarEnd" type="calendar" default="5-10-2008" label="End date" description="Select when the slide will be published" format="%d %B %Y" />
```

The problem is, when I open the module from the backend, pick a date, for example `23-10-2016` and save it, the next time I open the module , the date will display `22-10-2016`. No matter what date I pick, the module will substract a day when I open it.

The date saves correctly on the databse, because if I pick `23-10-2016` on the module, saves it, and then print it on the frontend, the website will display `23-10-2016` , but if I open the module on the backend, the date will display `22-10-2016`.

What can be causing the module to substract a day each time I open the module? Thank you

Comment: What time zone is your Joomla system set to in the Global Configuration?

Comment: I change the time zon from New York to Universal UTC and it worked.. thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I would guess there's an implicit timezone conversion happening. It's saving the time as midnight GMT in the DB, but on re-display, it's converting it to local time.

Comment: You are right. I change de Time Zone to Univeral UTC (It was set on new York) and it worked.  Thank you!!!!